# Unable to change Azure ALERT state

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I set up an **Alert** on an Azure storage account for Average storage consumption. In order to test it, I set the threshold consumption to 2TiB (my storage has 4 TiB data). As expected, the alert was fired meaning the setup was correct. Note: While setting up the alert I had selected the option `Automatically resolve alerts`.
[![Automatically resolve alerts- Enabled][1]][1]

**Issue**:-

Now I have increased this threshold to a much higher value it should actually be. However, the "state" of the alert already fired while testing is still present. **When I try to manually change it (set it to `Closed` or `Acknowledged`), it fails**. I've tried deleting the Alert altogether and re-creating it but even that did not help either.
[image: Alert State]

[image: Trying to change state]

[image: Unable to change state]

Comment: you can also try changing the state of the alert using [Alerts-Change state API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/change-state) Have you tried it does it helpful ?

Comment: To reproduce the issue in our local environment, we have created a web app & enabled alerts on it with a condition when the incoming requests are more than 5 for 1 minute. Post enabling the alerts at certain instant of time azure monitor has fired an alert triggered we are able to change the status of the alert using portal  as shown in this [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/yj3Ag95.gif).

Comment: The issue resolved itself over time. Seems it was one of those cases where Azure takes way too much time to update its state. I checked after about 24 hrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved itself over time. Seems it was one of those cases where Azure takes way too much time to update its state. I checked after about 24 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to lack of permissions

I have created a test user and assigned them Monitoring Reader for a project I'm building and they have the exact same issue as you

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#monitoring-reader

It looks like you need this permission to change the alert state
Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/changestate/action

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftalertsmanagement

You can also do this with the Monitoring Contributor RBAC Role
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#monitoring-contributor

Comment: The issue resolved itself over time. Seems it was one of those cases where Azure takes way too much time to update its state. I checked after about 24 hrs.